# How to automate webpage with iframes and drop down lists using excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, iframe, html, dropdown

I am trying to auto populate fields on a webpage using excel VBA. I am stuck on the drop down lists which are in an iframe.

Here is the website code that I am working with:

First the iframe code:

```
<iframe id="main_content_window" 
style="width:100%;height:99.5%;border:none;" onload="resizeEmbeddedPanel();" 
scrolling="yes" src="/system/workspace.php?
filter=overview&amp;is_runtime=true&amp;is_internal_admin=false"></iframe>
```

And here is the drop down menu that I'm trying to auto fill:

```
<select storage_var="1" object_id="270FBBA69CC911E786D7F8BC12333350" 
label_text="Choose+Program%3A" 
linked_var="DM:Submission.none.policy.line_of_business" 
context="270FBBA69CC911E786D7F8BC12333350" data_type="Text" 
id="270FBBA69CC911E786D7F8BC12333350_droplist_127072016125151333_FIELD" 
style="background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;cursor:default;;width:100%;" 
onselectstart="return true" field_data_type="Text" 
onkeydown="top.onFieldKeyDown(event, window, 0);" 
onkeyup="top.onFieldKeyUp(event, window, 0);" 
onpaste="top.onFieldKeyUp(event, window, 0);" onblur="return 
top.defaultBlurEvent(this, -1);" onchange="
return 
window.ev_270FBBA69CC911E786D7F8BC12333350_droplist
_127072016125151333_action(event); " date_format="mm/dd/yy" value="" 
class="">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="HO_FLD">Home &amp; Flood</option>
  <option value="FLD">Flood Only</option></select>
```

Everything is working until I get to the drop down menus on the webpage. This is what I have so far, I included what isn't working in my code (near the bottom):

```
Sub Superior()
Dim ieApp As Object
Dim div As Variant

'create a new instance of ie
Set ieApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ieApp.Visible = True

ieApp.navigate "website"

Wait 1
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

ieApp.document.all("login_email").Value = "username"
ieApp.document.all("login_password").Value = "password"
ieApp.document.all("login_button").Click

Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Wait 3

Dim button As HTMLInputButtonElement
Set button = 
ieApp.document.getElementById("internal_tab_text_client_products")
button.Focus
button.Click

Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim htmlWindow As MSHTML.HTMLWindow2
Set HTMLdoc = ieApp.document
Set htmlWindow = HTMLdoc.frames(0)

htmlWindow.execScript ("toggleNewBusinessMenu();")

htmlWindow.execScript ("launchNewBusiness('12','',null);")

Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

htmlWindow.document.all("_text_5204102016102444865_FIELD").Value = 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SUPERIOR").Range("a1")
htmlWindow.document.all("_text_5404102016102444866_FIELD").Value = 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SUPERIOR").Range("a2")

'Object variable or with block not set (1st option I tried)
HTMLdoc.getElementById("270FBBA69CC911E786D7F8BC12333350
_droplist_127072016125151333_FIELD").setAttribute "Value", "FLD"

'Object variable or with block not set (2nd option I tried)
HTMLdoc.getElementById("95BC5CFD99BA11E786D7F8BC12333350_droplist
_127072016125151333_FIELD").selectedIndex , 1

End Sub

Sub Wait(Seconds)
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "%COMSPEC% /c ping 127.0.0.1 -n " _
    & Seconds + 1, 0, True
End Sub
```

EDIT:

Appears that my code isn't recognizing the drop down. I've also tried using the following code:

```
Set HTMLdoc = ieApp.document
Set frame = HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("main_content_window")(0)
Set HTMLdoc = frame.contentDocument

HTMLdoc.querySelector("select[id='F6F136889A5511E786D7F8BC12333350_droplist
_127072016125151333_FIELD']").selectedIndex = 2
```

This also runs an error which says "Object variable or with block not set". Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Every time you navigate you need to get a fresh reference to HTMLDoc (since the page it refers to has been unloaded)

Comment: Hi Tim, so I tried adding in Set HTMLdoc = ieApp.document right before the code and waiting until it loads completely and it still says "Object variable or with block not set". Do you know what else it might be? Thanks!

Comment: If the element you're trying to access is inside of an iframe then you need to include that as you did for `Set htmlWindow = HTMLdoc.frames(0)`

Comment: Yes, I added both right before the drop down menu part of my code but still doesn't work.